# in ldap make the default bind the current logged in user

Tags: directory, ldap, sssd

I do not want to specify a default bind_dn in the sssd.conf file for ldap (either openldap or active directory). Is it possible to configure the system in a way, that the first logged in user becomes the "default bind dn" user - from what I see any logged in user has the necessary permission to do the "default bind dn" job, to search the ldap directory for groups and users. 
Therefore it would be nice if on a booted Linux (on which usally I am the only logged in user the first time), this functions which sssd requires to use would be my user, but without requiring to set a password in in sssd, simply by using my valid kerberos ticket from my login to search ldap, which i believe the default bind dn does most of the time.
Does anyboy have a solution, which would do such a trick?